Solana anza-xyz wallet not opening the transaction request window, posted bug on github, no answer
I posted the question here ↙️
https://github.com/anza-xyz/wallet-adapter/issues/981
I cant afford to launch a smart contract yet, so in the meantime I want to set it up in devnet and do test transactions on a alt coin but, I cant even initiate a transaction in the browser opera/chrome.
I am completely reliant on chat gpt and I'm not getting anywhere cause chat gpt just gives me solution with more errors and even messier code.
I don't know enough about this library to know why "isconnected" is showing up as false despite the fact it's clearly being logged at my widget footer. (example on the github issue link),
I have my entire code and a video posted. If I can get over this issue, development can progress much more smoothly so, I'd really appreciate someone to help me with this! it'd mean a lot!
